# Singly Linked List in C++ is not reading more than 2 nodes

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Below is a simple program for insertion in a linked list, however, whenever I run the program, it reads only two input values for the list and stops further execution. Why is that? I am unable to catch the issue.

```
/**** Defining structure of node *****/
class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;     
        Node(int val){
            data = val;
            next = NULL;
        }
};

/**** Inserting node at the end ****/
Node* insertAtEnd(Node* &head, int val){
    Node* n = new Node(val);
    if(head == NULL){
        head = n;
    }
    Node* tmp = head;
    while(tmp->next != NULL){
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = n;
    return tmp;
}

/**** Menu ****/
int menu(){
    int ch;
    cout<<"1. Insert node"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
    cin>>ch;
    cout<<endl;
    return(ch);
}

/**** Driver Code ****/
int main(){
    Node* head = NULL; int n, data;
    switch(menu()){
        case 1:
            cout<<"\nEnter number of nodes you want to enter: ";
            cin>>n;
            for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
                cout<<"Enter data: ";
                cin>>data;
                insertAtEnd(head, data);
            }
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Wrong Choice";
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that your InsertAtEndFunction does not correctly handle the case when head is NULL. You are ending up with a list where head->next == head.

Comment: People need to stop teaching C-style linked lists when C++ is the language.

Comment: You should maintain a pointer to the last node in the list.  This would make inserting at the end of the list a lot more efficient.

Comment: @SvenNilsson yeah, I should have added return after head = n; thanks a lot

Comment: Also check whether you need to return `temp` or `head` inside insertAtEnd function

Comment: @ManyaSharma It would be better to re-write `insertAtEnd()` to eliminate the `if` block completely, eg: `Node* insertAtEnd(Node* &head, int val){ Node** n = &head; while (*n) { n = &((*n)->next); } *n = new Node(val); return *n; }` Even better, if you do what ThomasMathews suggested and maintain a separate `tail` pointer, then you don't have to hunt for the end of the list each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `insertAtEnd` needs an early return with the first node, or it will ran into a infinite loop.

```cpp
  Node* insertAtEnd(int val) {
    Node* n = new Node(val);
    if (head == NULL) {
      head = n;
      return head;
    }
    Node* tmp = head;
    while (tmp->next != NULL) {
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = n;
    return tmp;
  }
```

Your code is mostly c-style and hasn't dealt with memory deallocation, so memory is leaked.

I have added on `list` class to make it more naturally in C++, add use destructor to free the dynamic memory.

```cpp
struct List {
  Node* head = nullptr;

  Node* insertAtEnd(int val) {
    Node* n = new Node(val);
    if (head == NULL) {
      head = n;
      return head;
    }
    Node* tmp = head;
    while (tmp->next != NULL) {
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = n;
    return tmp;
  }
  ~List() {
    while (head) {
      auto tmp = head->next;
      delete head;
      head = tmp;
    }
  }
};
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q59Phafah)

Comment: Using a destructor is really new to me, I'll definitely try this one. Also never in entire semester our professor mentioned 'auto' keyword, I'll also check upon this one. Thanks:)

Comment: @ManyaSharma You need a modern c++ text book,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @prehistoricoenguin it solved my problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ManyaSharma  Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

In function add Node at the end of List, i think you should **pass by value** the pointer "Node* head"   **NOT pass by reference**  "Node*& head" .
I actually coded like that and my code runned correctly without any bug. You can refer my code below

```
Node* addtail(Node* head, int value) {   //  
    Node* p;
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = value;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {                  // if head empty => head = temp instantly 
        head = temp;
    }
    else {
        p = head;
        while (p->next != NULL) {         
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = temp;
    }
    return head;
}
```